# How to get access to Google Drive from terminal

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

I am new to mac yosemite I have the list of my folder "Google Drive"
I can see this from ls -la command , but when I want to cd to it it said not exist ? [image]

How can I actually get access to this drive via terminal ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Arguments to commands in Bash (the language used in Terminal) are separated by spaces. So when you write `cd Google Drive`, you're passing two arguments to `cd` - `Google` and `Drive`. `cd` is just ignoring the second argument and trying to cd into the directory called `Google`, which doesn't exist.

In order to cd into `Google Drive`, you need to write `cd Google\ Drive` or `cd "Google Drive"`. The `\` escapes the space character and treats it as a single string.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone looking for how to do this after Drive's recent updates... at the moment (June 2022) Drive files are stored in the following location:

`/Users/_USERNAME_/Library/CloudStorage/_DRIVE_FOLDER_NAME_`

If you are looking to access your files in a terminal window, the easiest way to get there may simply be to do the following:

- Open a Finder window
- If it's not already showing, go to the View menu and click "View Path Bar"
- In the path bar (at the bottom of your Finder window), right-click on the home folder for your Google Drive account and click "Open in Terminal"

Comment: `/Volumes/GoogleDrive` for Google Drive version 58.0 (2022-June-12).

Answer (score 2):

As Google Drive has a space in between the words you need to quote the directory name.

Try `cd 'Google Drive'`

Answer (score 2):

I would also type `cd Goo` and then press `tab`so it would autocomplete with the escaped space character.

Comment: This is a more practical answer (though it doesn't explain the problem)

Answer (score 2):

In my case `cd /Volumes/DATA/.CMVolumes/Google\ Drive/`

Answer (score 0):

The `cd Google\ Drive` command seems to work for me.